# if condition in sql | codeigner

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have 2 table, one for:

> user information

second for:

> "user last activity"

I have code to fetch and display all user on the page, each user should display his state, - everything  is work as shown in my code

**BUT**

- I want to make my code **clean**, so I want to move the "if
  condition" in my view page to model page when the state is empty in
  the table,
- I want to display all my user with users state in my page without
  using if condition in the view page.

***My code:***

---

**DataBase:**

[image]

**My Page:**

[image]

**View:**

```
<?php   foreach($Users as $c){  ?>

<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th> 
<th>Last Activity Time</th>
 <th>State</th>
 <th>User ID</th>
   </tr>
    <tr>
  <td><?php echo $c->email ?></td>
<td><?php echo $c->type ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $c->last_activity ?></td>


<td>
    <!-- this code is run good , but i want to change it to contolloer to make the code clean  , 
    and if i changed to controller hw i can call the state here --> 
   <?php $current_timestamp = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . '- 10 second');
    $current_timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $current_timestamp); 
     if($c->last_activity > $current_timestamp)
            {
            echo "online";
            }
        else
            {
            echo "offline";
            } ?>
```

**Model:**

```
 public function getAllUsers() //from 1 table
   { 

 $this->db->select('m.user_id, m.email , m.type, u.last_activity   ,u.id  ,u.state');
$this->db->from('tbl_user m');
$this->db->join('tbl_user_activity u ', 'u.user_id = m.user_id' ,'LEFT');
$this->db->select_max('u.last_activity');
// $this->db->where($where);
$this->db->group_by('m.user_id');// add group_by
$query = $this->db->get();

 foreach ($query as $c)
 {     
    $current_timestamp = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . '- 10 second');
    $current_timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $current_timestamp);

        if('$c->last_activity' > $current_timestamp) //try
            { // here must to be function to checl the last user activity and get it

             // here must to set the u.state to online 

            }
        else if($query < $current_timestamp) //try
            {

            } 

 }
return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

> What if you check and set "state" in your MODEL/CONTROLLER page

```
MODEL PAGE
<?php
    //your code, 
    $last_activity = $c->last_activity; //make sure it won't return NULL

    if($last_activity > $current_timestamp) { //return true if online,
        $state = "online";
    }else{
        $state = "offline";
    }
    //your code, 
?>
```

> just read the state in your VIEW page

```
VIEW PAGE
<?php
    //your code, 
    $new_state = $c->state; //so $new_state = "online" or $new_state = "offline"
    //your code, 
?>
```

Comment: i try this befor , when make this , it change all state in all record , i have to be sbesific to show the last activy for this user , then changd this state

Comment: @nojoudkaled Could you please describe more details about _when make this , it change all state in all record_ ? Since you embed these code in a foreach loop, it should work and display corresponding online/offline status respectively.

Comment: no it changed all recod , in foreach , we have to again desctip what user id , and wheat last activity for this user id

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
It will create a new collection of data with a new row called 'state';
The return value is an array so you should probably change your view to loop an array instead of an object.

```
$query = $this->db->get()->result_result_array();
$new_record = array();

foreach($query as $old_record)
{
    $current_timestamp = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . '- 10 second');
    $current_timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $current_timestamp);

        if('$c->last_activity' > $current_timestamp) //try
            { 
              $new_record[]['state'] = 'online';
              $new_record[] = $old_record;
            }
        else if($query < $current_timestamp) //try
            {
              $new_record[]['state'] = 'offline';
              $new_record[] = $old_record;
            }
}

return $new_record;
```